# Getting error only when value is passed in json string in httpwebrequest

Tags: c#, json, httpwebrequest

I am peforming HttpWebRequest to perform POST method. I get error only when I pass value otherwise It's working perfectly.

Code:

```
 public void CreateOrganization(string accountname)
    {
        var http = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(baseAddress));
        http.Accept = "application/json";
        http.ContentType = "application/json";
        http.Method = "POST";
        string parsedContent = "{\"name\":\" "+accountname+" \"}";
        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        Byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(parsedContent);
        Stream newStream = http.GetRequestStream();
        newStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        newStream.Close();
        var response = http.GetResponse();
        var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
        var content = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

It stops working at Stream newStream = http.GetRequestStream(); .

Comment: what is the exception? what is the value of `parsedContent` when you pass in a value? Does that look correct per your expectations?

Comment: Ya Values are correct.

Comment: What is the error message that you are recieving?

Comment: I don't get any error message. debugging gets stop.